# How to notify by email if CPU usage is above a certain threshold

Tags: sql-server

In `Microsoft SQL Server 2022 Standard` I cannot get notification for CPU % usage to trigger.

I have found the [following question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181954/cpu-usage-alert-is-not-working-for-alert-if-counter-raises-above/182107) but it does not apply as the resource governor is not available to my version and I get the following message from MSSQL itself

> The resource governor is not available in this edition of SQL Server. Only Enterprise edition of
> SQL Server supports resource governor.

I tried both `Workload Group Stats` and `Resource Pool Stats` for the `CPU usage %` but in the history tab where it state `Date of last alert` it says `(never occured)`

Documentation on the subject is inexistant at best. I tried on 3 other MSSQL Servers (a mix of 2012 and 2016) and they don't work either. Is it just an option they forgot to remove from the Standard version UI for 10 years straight or it it somehow usable ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Workload Groups and Resource Pools are both Resource Governor artifacts.  So it's not surprising they don't work on Standard edition.  You can try monitoring when sessions need, but must wait for a CPU, like this

[image]

Or you can monitor the CPU through the Windows Performance Counters in Windows or other monitoring solution.  eg

[image]